# Pegar trecho de uma string entre () e alterá-lo em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Tenho uma string em texto no seguinte formato:

> Tamanho 35 (5 Unidades)

Eu preciso pegar os números que estão dentro dos parênteses, rodar uma função (que já está pronta) e devolver um novo número no lugar.

O problema é quando o exemplo fica

> Tamanho 3 (3 Unidades)

Quando retorno a função, que é uma subtração, e há dois números iguais, ela atualiza o primeiro número e não o que está dentro do parênteses, ficando assim:

> Tamanho 2 (3 Unidades)

E eu preciso que ela fique desta forma, neste exemplo:

> Tamanho 3 (2 Unidades)

Meu código está assim:

```
this.optionSelect = product.querySelectorAll("select");
//Lista todos os campos tipo SELECT
this.optionSelect.forEach(item => {
        let selectText = item.options[item.selectedIndex].innerText;
        //Pega o texto da tag OPTION
        let removePar = selectText.split("(");
        let replaceSelectQty = removePar.replace(/\D/g, '');


        for (let match of selectText.matchAll(/\([^)\d]*(\d+)[^)\d]*\)/g)) {
            var a = match[1];
            item.options[item.selectedIndex].innerText.replace(a, parseInt(replaceSelectQty)-parseInt(this.inputQty.value));
            //Atualiza o texto da tag OPTION, mas se o primeiro número for o mesmo da quantidade, ele atualiza o primeiro número e não a quantidade que está dentro dos parênteses
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode mudar sua regex, colocando mais grupos de captura (ou seja, mais trechos entre parênteses). Isso cria mais [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) e permite que você faça a substituição do trecho correto:

```js
function mudarNumero(n) { // uma função qualquer que muda o valor
    return parseInt(n) - 1;
}

let selectText = 'Tamanho 3 (3 Unidades)';
let novoTexto = selectText.replace(/(\([^)\d]*)(\d+)([^)\d]*\))/g,
    function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
        return `${p1}${mudarNumero(p2)}${p3}`;
    }
);
console.log(novoTexto); // Tamanho 3 (2 Unidades)
```

Agora há 3 trechos entre parênteses (e portanto, 3 grupos de captura):

1. `(\([^)\d]*)`: o parênteses de abertura e zero ou mais caracteres que não é número nem `)`. Ou seja, é tudo desde o `(` até antes do número
2. `(\d+)`: um ou mais dígitos de 0 a 9
3. `([^)\d]*\))`: zero ou mais caracteres que não é número nem `)`, seguido do parênteses de fechamento. Ou seja, é tudo depois do número até o `)`.

Na [função passada como *callback* para `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), tenho os parâmetros `p1`, `p2` e `p3`, que correspondem respectivamente aos grupos 1, 2 e 3 descritos acima. O retorno da função monta outra string com `p1` e `p3` sem modificação, e entre eles eu chamo a função que modifica o valor de `p2` (que é o número que está entre parênteses).

Assim a regex só substitui o número que estiver entre parênteses, ignorando o que está fora deles.

---

Se a string tiver vários parênteses, e dentro de cada um tiver mais de um número, aí a solução é um pouco diferente. Neste caso, eu pego cada trecho entre parênteses e em seguida substituo todos os números dentro deles:

```js
function mudarNumero(n) { // uma função qualquer que muda o valor
    return parseInt(n) - 1;
}

let selectText = 'Tamanho 3 (3 Unidades 33 abc 3 xyz 44 def) lorem 4 ipsum (4 dolor 44 sit)';
let novoTexto = selectText;
// para cada conteúdo dentro de parênteses
for (const match of selectText.matchAll(/\(([^)]+)\)/g)) {
    // troca todos os números pelo retorno da função que muda o valor
    let s = match[1].replace(/(\d+)/g,
        function(match, p1) {
            return mudarNumero(p1);
        }
    );
    novoTexto = novoTexto.replace(`(${match[1]})`, `(${s})`);
}
console.log(novoTexto); // Tamanho 3 (2 Unidades 32 abc 2 xyz 43 def) lorem 4 ipsum (3 dolor 43 sit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo sua abordagem, com poucas modificações, daria para fazer assim:

```js
function go(){

            let select = document.querySelector("select");

            let currentSelectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        
            let stringToHandle = currentSelectedOption.innerText;
        
            for (let match of stringToHandle.matchAll(/\([^)\d]*(\d+)[^)\d]*\)/g)) {
            
                let fullParentesisText = match[0];
                let number = match[1];

                let newFullParentesisText = fullParentesisText.replace(number, 
                    parseInt(number) - 2
                );

                let newFullText = stringToHandle.replace(fullParentesisText,
                    newFullParentesisText
                )

                currentSelectedOption.innerText = newFullText;
            
            }
        
        }
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="one">Tamanho 35 (5 Unidades)</option>
    <option value="two">Tamanho 3 (3 Unidades)</option>
</select>

<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
```